# Flutter http.get not getting body data

Tags: json, flutter, dart, flutter-http

I am trying to get the data from my json feed which is this [Json](https://studiofutbol.com.ec/api/json/feed_master.php?pagina=)

But when I try to use the body result it is not working ( but it works with other jsons like this one https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users), my code looks like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'noticias.dart';

class Services {
static const String url =
  'https://studiofutbol.com.ec/api/json/feed_master.php?pagina=';

static Future<Portada> getNoticias() async {
try {
  var headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
  };
  final response = await http.get(url, headers: headers);
  debugPrint(response.body);
  if (200 == response.statusCode) {
    final Portada noticiasportada = portadaFromJson(response.body);
    return noticiasportada;
  } else {
    return Portada();
  }
} catch (e) {
  return Portada();
}
  }
}
```

I added those headers but it did not help, what could be causing the issue?

Comment: Can you add error or response to the question?

Comment: Please add `debugPrint(response.body);` what you are getting here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work for me like this

```
Future<Portada> getNoticias() async {
    try {
      HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
      HttpClientRequest request = await httpClient.getUrl(Uri.parse(
          "https://studiofutbol.com.ec/api/json/feed_master.php?pagina="));
      request.headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
     
      HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();
      String reply = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      print(reply);
      httpClient.close();
      Map<String, dynamic> map = json.decode(reply);
      final Portada noticiasportada = Portada.fromMap(map);
      return noticiasportada;
    } catch (e) {
      return Portada();
    }
  }
```

Model Class

```
import 'dart:convert';

Portada portadaFromMap(String str) => Portada.fromMap(json.decode(str));

String portadaToMap(Portada data) => json.encode(data.toMap());

class Portada {
  Portada({
    this.json,
    this.menu,
    this.banners,
    this.tags,
    this.equipos,
    this.menuIos,
    this.version,
    this.versionIos,
  });

  List<Json> json;
  List<Menu> menu;
  Banners banners;
  List<Tag> tags;
  List<Equipo> equipos;
  List<MenuIo> menuIos;
  String version;
  String versionIos;

  factory Portada.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Portada(
    json: json["Json"] == null ? null : List<Json>.from(json["Json"].map((x) => Json.fromMap(x))),
    menu: json["menu"] == null ? null : List<Menu>.from(json["menu"].map((x) => Menu.fromMap(x))),
    banners: json["banners"] == null ? null : Banners.fromMap(json["banners"]),
    tags: json["tags"] == null ? null : List<Tag>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => Tag.fromMap(x))),
    equipos: json["equipos"] == null ? null : List<Equipo>.from(json["equipos"].map((x) => Equipo.fromMap(x))),
    menuIos: json["menu_ios"] == null ? null : List<MenuIo>.from(json["menu_ios"].map((x) => MenuIo.fromMap(x))),
    version: json["version"] == null ? null : json["version"],
    versionIos: json["version_ios"] == null ? null : json["version_ios"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "Json": json == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    "menu": menu == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(menu.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    "banners": banners == null ? null : banners.toMap(),
    "tags": tags == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    "equipos": equipos == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(equipos.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    "menu_ios": menuIos == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(menuIos.map((x) => x.toMap())),
    "version": version == null ? null : version,
    "version_ios": versionIos == null ? null : versionIos,
  };
}

class Banners {
  Banners({
    this.splash,
    this.splashiphone,
    this.main,
    this.interna,
  });

  Interna splash;
  Interna splashiphone;
  Interna main;
  Interna interna;

  factory Banners.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Banners(
    splash: json["splash"] == null ? null : Interna.fromMap(json["splash"]),
    splashiphone: json["splashiphone"] == null ? null : Interna.fromMap(json["splashiphone"]),
    main: json["main"] == null ? null : Interna.fromMap(json["main"]),
    interna: json["interna"] == null ? null : Interna.fromMap(json["interna"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "splash": splash == null ? null : splash.toMap(),
    "splashiphone": splashiphone == null ? null : splashiphone.toMap(),
    "main": main == null ? null : main.toMap(),
    "interna": interna == null ? null : interna.toMap(),
  };
}

class Interna {
  Interna({
    this.imagen,
    this.link,
  });

  String imagen;
  String link;

  factory Interna.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Interna(
    imagen: json["imagen"] == null ? null : json["imagen"],
    link: json["link"] == null ? null : json["link"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "imagen": imagen == null ? null : imagen,
    "link": link == null ? null : link,
  };
}

class Equipo {
  Equipo({
    this.id,
    this.nombre,
  });

  int id;
  String nombre;

  factory Equipo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Equipo(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    nombre: json["nombre"] == null ? null : json["nombre"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "nombre": nombre == null ? null : nombre,
  };
}

class Json {
  Json({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.titleint,
    this.permalink,
    this.content,
    this.excerpt,
    this.date,
    this.author,
    this.image,
    this.fuente,
    this.thumbnail,
    this.categories,
    this.tags,
    this.contentIphone,
    this.videoEnlace,
  });

  int id;
  String title;
  String titleint;
  String permalink;
  String content;
  String excerpt;
  DateTime date;
  String author;
  List<dynamic> image;
  String fuente;
  String thumbnail;
  List<String> categories;
  List<String> tags;
  String contentIphone;
  String videoEnlace;

  factory Json.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Json(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    title: json["title"] == null ? null : json["title"],
    titleint: json["titleint"] == null ? null : json["titleint"],
    permalink: json["permalink"] == null ? null : json["permalink"],
    content: json["content"] == null ? null : json["content"],
    excerpt: json["excerpt"] == null ? null : json["excerpt"],
    date: json["date"] == null ? null : DateTime.parse(json["date"]),
    author: json["author"] == null ? null : json["author"],
    image: json["image"] == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(json["image"].map((x) => x)),
    fuente: json["fuente"] == null ? null : json["fuente"],
    thumbnail: json["thumbnail"] == null ? null : json["thumbnail"],
    categories: json["categories"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["categories"].map((x) => x)),
    tags: json["tags"] == null ? null : List<String>.from(json["tags"].map((x) => x)),
    contentIphone: json["contentIphone"] == null ? null : json["contentIphone"],
    videoEnlace: json["video_enlace"] == null ? null : json["video_enlace"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "title": title == null ? null : title,
    "titleint": titleint == null ? null : titleint,
    "permalink": permalink == null ? null : permalink,
    "content": content == null ? null : content,
    "excerpt": excerpt == null ? null : excerpt,
    "date": date == null ? null : date.toIso8601String(),
    "author": author == null ? null : author,
    "image": image == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(image.map((x) => x)),
    "fuente": fuente == null ? null : fuente,
    "thumbnail": thumbnail == null ? null : thumbnail,
    "categories": categories == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(categories.map((x) => x)),
    "tags": tags == null ? null : List<dynamic>.from(tags.map((x) => x)),
    "contentIphone": contentIphone == null ? null : contentIphone,
    "video_enlace": videoEnlace == null ? null : videoEnlace,
  };
}

class Menu {
  Menu({
    this.url,
    this.nombre,
  });

  String url;
  String nombre;

  factory Menu.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Menu(
    url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
    nombre: json["nombre"] == null ? null : json["nombre"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "url": url == null ? null : url,
    "nombre": nombre == null ? null : nombre,
  };
}

class MenuIo {
  MenuIo({
    this.nombre,
    this.url,
    this.segue,
    this.img,
  });

  String nombre;
  String url;
  String segue;
  String img;

  factory MenuIo.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => MenuIo(
    nombre: json["nombre"] == null ? null : json["nombre"],
    url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
    segue: json["segue"] == null ? null : json["segue"],
    img: json["img"] == null ? null : json["img"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "nombre": nombre == null ? null : nombre,
    "url": url == null ? null : url,
    "segue": segue == null ? null : segue,
    "img": img == null ? null : img,
  };
}

class Tag {
  Tag({
    this.id,
    this.nombre,
    this.url,
  });

  int id;
  String nombre;
  String url;

  factory Tag.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Tag(
    id: json["id"] == null ? null : json["id"],
    nombre: json["nombre"] == null ? null : json["nombre"],
    url: json["url"] == null ? null : json["url"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "id": id == null ? null : id,
    "nombre": nombre == null ? null : nombre,
    "url": url == null ? null : url,
  

 };
}
```

Comment: Hey, your model class looks so neat and clean, Can you please tell me by which tool you have generated it ?

Comment: This worked thanks, but what would be the problem with the method I am using?

Comment: Lots of Thanks, @GursewakSingh